# Instalar paquete de Python 3.x sin internet

Tags: python, python-3.x

No es una pregunta de código, básicamente no he podido encontrar algo similar a esto.

Hice un desarrollo en Python que debo ejecutar en un computador de escritorio, pero el problema que ese computador no tiene conexión a internet y necesito tener instalado el paquete Pandas. ¿Se puede instalar Pandas sin tener internet, llevándolo descargado en un pendrive por ejemplo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La opción más directa es descargarte los archivos .whl desde PyPI (Python Package Index) e instalarlos con pip.

Para ello descargate los whl de todas las dependencias de Pandas, que creo que son:

- [Pytz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz)
- [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/2.6.1)
- [NumPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy)

Y por supuesto [Pandas](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/0.20.3).

Para cada paquete te descargas el whl adecuado al sistema operativo (incluido si es 32 o 64 bits) y a la versión de Python en la que vas a realizar la instalación. Posteriormente usas pip pero apuntando a la ruta del archivo whl. Instalas primero las dependencias y por último Pandas, por ejemplo (para Windows, Python 3.6, 64 bits, con los whl en la ruta *E:/Descargas*):

- `py -3.6 -m pip install E:/Descargas/pytz-2017.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl`
- `py -3.6 -m pip install E:/Descargas/python_dateutil-2.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl`
- `py -3.6 -m pip install E:/Descargas/numpy-1.13.1-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl`
- `py -3.6 -m pip install E:/Descargas/pandas-0.20.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Si es para Windows y tienes problemas de compilación puedes usar los binarios precompilados que proporciona Christoph Gohlke de la Universidad de California en vez de los whl de PyPI:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

El procedimiento es el mismo.

Generalmente vas a encontrar el archivo whl para casi todos los paquetes distribuidos en PyPi, no obstante puedes encontrarte con algunos que solo están disponibles mediante las fuentes. Estas se encuentran en archivos comprimidos de tipo *zip* o *tar.gz*.

- Instalación con **pip**:

  - Se descomprime el fichero usando un programa adecuado como 7-Zip.
  - Se instalan con pip usando el argumento `-e` seguido de la ruta del directorio donde se encuentra el fichero descomprimido:

    ```
    py -3.6 -m pip install -e package_directory
    ```
- Usando el archivo **setup.py**:

  - Descomprimimos el archivo igual que antes.
  - Abrimos la terminal/consola y nos situamos dentro del directorio donde hemos descomprimido el archivo (donde se encuentra *setup.py*).
  - Instalamos usando el archivo *setup.py* que se encuentra en dicho fichero:

    ```
    py -3.6 setup.py install
    ```

---

Una opción algo menos manual es construirnos nuestro propio directorio con todo lo necesario usando [`pip wheel`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/), en la terminal en un Pc con conexion hacemos:

```
py -3.6 -m pip wheel --wheel-dir=D:/Descargas/wheelhouse pandas
```

Esto nos crea un directorio en `D:/Descargas/` (cambiar por la ruta necesaria) con todo lo necesario para instalar Pandas (dependencias incluidas). Podemos copiarlo así o comprimirlo primero. Copiamos esto en el ordenador sin conexión (como ejemplo se usa `D:/Descargas/` como ruta) y ejecutamos en la terminal:

```
py -3.6 -m pip install --no-index --find-links=D:/Descargas/wheelhouse pandas
```

---

Otra opción sería usar [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/) que tiene Pandas entre las librerias incluidas en el instalador entre muchas otras (en torno a 100 como puede verse en la siguiente [lista](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs)).

> **Nota**: Los comandos de terminal son solo a modo de ejemplo.En este caso son para el supuesto de instalar paquetes en Windows sobre Python 3.6 usando el Python Launcher. No obstante, la idea es válida para otros sistemas operativos/versiones de Python, basta con llamar de forma correcta a pip en cada caso.

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla Yo tengo instalado miniconda, pero anaconda viene con los paquetes incluidos?

Comment: @JorgePonti, si trae Pandas (y sus dependencias) incluidos en el instalador, además de muchos otros. Puedes ver la lista en: https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs. La pega es que son 360 Mb de ejecutable... No la he instalado nunca en un PC sin conexión pero no recuerdo que fuera necesaria durante el proceso de instalación en ningún momento.

Comment: Gracias, estaba mirando la lista, hay uno que uso y que no está es "gspread", ese lo tendré que instalar con la otra forma.

Comment: @JorgePonti no se si con `gspread` te refieres a https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gspread. De ser así solo dispones de las fuentes en este caso (no hay whl disponible). De cualquier forma, he actualizado la respuesta por si alguien se encuentra en este supuesto,  si tienes cualquier problema coméntalo. Saludos.

Comment: Estoy tratando de hacerlo utilizando setup.py pero en la línea de comandos debo, ir a Python primero? ya que directamente me tira error. Yo tengo instalado Anaconda

Comment: @JorgePonti has probado primero con `pip -e ....`? Es preferible esto a usar el setup.py directamente. ¿Qué error te da? ¿Instalas dentro de un entorno virtual  con Anaconda?

Comment: Ahora pude gracias lo hice así "python -m pip install -e C:\Users\4209456\Downloads\gspread-0.6.2.tar\dist\gspread-0.6.2"

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64156/discussion-between-jorge-ponti-and-fjsevilla).